# Why does a shock help restore capacitive touchscreen function?

Tags: capacitance

https://youtu.be/uUC3h0b7_5c

The LG G2 smart phone often develops a unresponsive touchscreen. Many people have reported that taking the igniter out of a lighter and actuating it against the touchscreen restores function.

What's the mechanism behind this "trick"?

Comment: Shocking electronic devices with a piezo is a bad idea. I wonder how many people kill their phones this way.

Answer (score 1):

Electrical telephone lines can develop short circuits which cause degradation or failure of the service.

The telephone line normally works on about 48 V. To cure a weak short, the telephone company can try applying a substantially higher voltage on the line. This increases the current through the short and can break the short, like a fuse blowing.

Restoring the functionality of a capacitive touchscreen with about 800 V from a piezo igniter could work the same way.